# Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, gradle, stripe-payments

I need to launch a small delivery App from Visual Studio Code(using own physical device), `flutter run` throws me this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KJ5 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
You are applying Flutter's main Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).

  Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
  Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation 

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             15.8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my android/app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace "com.ivc.lili"

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ivc.lili"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    //For AGP 7.4+ https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html *MIGRACION* 
    implementation coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    
    constraints { implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android') { version { strictly '20.11.0' } } } 
    constraints { implementation('com.stripe:financial-connections') { version { strictly '20.11.0' } } }
}
```

This is my android/build.gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my android/settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false
}

include ":app"
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
```

Android Studio Gradle SDK:
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ0ez.jpg).
I followed some documentation [packages](https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc) Also did some `flutter clean` but same error persist.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```kotlin
kotlinOptions {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

To just this, so that the target is set for all tasks (and therefore also task `compileDebugJavaWithJavac`):

```kotlin
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
```

If that does not work, you can also try the suggested JVM toolchain:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version("0.5.0")
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
```